# Adjusting a range with weighting

Tags: c, function, range

I have created a little game of Rock Scissor Paper. I have made it so the first 10 games are played with the computer responding with random moves (based on a random number between 0-100 falling in an equally divided range).

However, in the second set of 10 games I am wanting the computers response to be weighted based off the players responses to the first 10 games. 
I have written this below, however it applies a 100% weight.

I would like to apply only a 50% weight to the range, any ideas on what would be the simplest method to achieve this?

This is a function I have written so is only part of the code

```
    int z;
    float range[5];
    float player_r, player_s, player_p, games;

    player_r = (float)playertotal_R;
    player_s = (float)playertotal_S;
    player_p = (float)playertotal_P;

    games = (float)totalgames;

    z = rand() % 101;

    range[0] = player_s / games * 101.0;
    range[1] = range[0] + 0.1;
    range[2] = (range[0]) + (player_p / games * 100.0);
    range[3] = range[2] + 0.1;
    range[4] = 100.0;


    if (z <= range[0]) {
        strcpy(compresponse[w], "r");
        computertotal_R++;
    } else if ((z >= range[1]) && (z <= range[2])) {
        strcpy(compresponse[w], "s");
        computertotal_S++;
    } else if ((z >= range[3]) && (z <= range[4])) {
        strcpy(compresponse[w], "p");
        computertotal_P++;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some observations on your existing code:

- Since your ranges are rational numbers, it might be better not to produce an integer in the range from 0 to 99, but to produce a random floating-point number between 0 and 1 (exclusively):

  ```
  z = rand() / (1.0 + RAND_MAX);
  ```
- When you have three outcomes, you don't need five limits. It is enough to find the intermediate limits between rock and paper and paper and scissors. You also don't need to check both sides of the range, because the lower side is already taken care of by the `else`:

  ```
  double prob_rock = 1.0 / 3.0;
  double prob_paper = 2.0 / 3.0;

  if (z < prob_rock) {
      // Rock
  } else if (z < prob_paper) {
      // Paper
  } else {
      // Scissors
  }
  ```

As for your desired distribution:

- You can adjust your range so that the previous moves of the player are taken into account only half of the time by distributing the probability:

  ```
  p[move] = 0.5 * p[countermove] + 0.5 * p[regular]
  ```

  or in the example above:

  ```
  double prob_rock = 0.5 * npaper / games + 0.5 / 3.0;
  double prob_paper = 0.5 * nscissors / games + 1.0 / 3.0;
  ```
- Another possibility to achieve that is to toss a coin (of 50% chance) first and use the regular distribution on heads and the countermove to the player's statistic (as in your code) otherwise.
- If you keep an array of the player's moves so far, you can just pick one of the past moves and chose the correct countermove for it.

Comment: Thanks M Oehm. Very informative and has helped greatly :) Appreciate it